# What is this sum equals to?

Tags: complex-analysis

Im trying to compute $a_i,b_i $ are complex numbers

$$ \sum_{n \geq 0, k \geq 1, n+k = 0 } a_n \overline{b_k} r^{n-k} + \sum_{n \geq 1, k \geq 0, k+n = 0} b_n \overline{a_k} r^{k-n} $$

Does this sum equals to zero ? I am having hard time trying to see how to simplify it.

Update: I think I got it now: It must be zero because since $n \geq 0 $ and $k \geq 1 $, then it is not possible for $n+k$ to be zero, so we are summing over an empty set. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes those sums container no terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summing conditions `n≥0,k≥1` (or `n≥1,k≥0` for the second sigma) imply $n+k\ge 1$. A condition `n+k=0` makes a contradiction, so the three conditions together define an empty set of $(n,k)$ pairs. And an empty sum is considered $0$ (zero).